# why future continuous

Tags: progressive-aspect

> Will you stock this book?
>
> I will be getting copies of it.

My question is, why future continuous tense? Is it equivalent to the present continuous, "I have arranged it and I am getting them pretty soon", or is future continuous being used because it will take a long time to get them?

Answer (score 1):

I see it as a direct answer to the initial question:

> **Will** you stock this book?

Which could be answered in only one of two general ways, assuming they do not have the book in stock already:

> (Yes,) I **will** be getting copies of it (but I don't have them yet).

As opposed to

> (No,) I **will not** be getting any copies of it.

In this context, I don't think you can infer any specifics on the timing based on the use of tense alone.  All you can infer is that they are planning to stock the book at some point in the future.

Also, as for the initial question, it may be more correct to say

> Will you be stocking this book?

If you ask it in the other tense, it conjures to mind the image of a bookshop owner handing new books to an employee and asking for them to be placed on the shelf.

Comment: Agreed about that last part for sure. "Will you stock this book?" is much more something a boss would say to an employ - a polite sort of command.